# Forwarding annotation value from declaration

Tags: java, spring, annotations

is it possible to forward value of annotation from declaration?
Example:

```
@Component
public class A {

 @Autowired
 @Value(value = "sessionFactory1")   //forward value "sessionFactory1" into Dao
 private Dao dao;
}

@Repository
public class Dao {

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier(<value>)                //get value for @Qualifier ("sessionFactory1") from declaration in class A
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

Something like that.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't define one bean from another bean as you are trying to do and you shouldn't. If it worked, you would be adding a dependency from class `A` to the `SessionFactory`, while the dependency should really only be between `Dao` and `SessionFactory`.